# Can both of $(x+1)(x+3)$ and $(x-1)(x-3)$ are rational numbers imply $(x+1)^2$ is rational?

Tags: solution-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I do this problem in the homework paper and I think both of $(x+1)(x+3)$ and $(x-1)(x-3)$ are rational can imply $(x+1)(x+3)-(x-1)(x-3)=8x$ is rational and then $(x+1)^2$ is rational.
But the answer shows both of $(x+1)(x+3)$ and $(x-1)(x-3)$ are rational cannot imply $(x+1)^2$ is rational. I am not sure whether me or the answer is incorrect.
Can you help me?

Edit: Recheck the question, and I am sorry that I ignore one condition "x is irrational", so the answer is correct. Noticed in fact that condition 1 and 2 cannot hold at the same time.

Question: x is irrational, then can imply $(x+1)^2$ is irrational.
Condition 1: $(x+1)(x+3)$ is rational
condition 2: $(x-1)(x-3)$ is rational
Choose:
A: condition 1 is sufficient
B: condition 2 is sufficient
C: none of condition 1 or 2 is sufficient but condition 1 + 2 is sufficient
D: both of condition 1 and 2 is sufficient
E: none of condition 1 or 2 is sufficient and condition 1+2 is insufficient

Comment: It seems you're right : if $a = (x+1)(x+3)$ and $b = (x-1)(x-3)$ then $(x+1)^2 = \left(\frac{a-b}{8}+1\right)^2$ is a composition of functions that retain rationality, hence it is rational.

Comment: What you did is correct.

Comment: I'd like to see more information on the "answer" that allegedly shows you can't conclude $(x+1)^2$ is rational. How exactly does the "answer" support that allegation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding to comments.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, the answer said (x+1)(x+3) is irrational then imply x is irrational, so is (x−1)(x−3), thus (x+1)^2 is irrational. I think it may ignore some details so ask the question on site.

Comment: If $x=\sqrt2+2$, then $(x+1)(x+3)$ is irrational, and so is $x$, but $(x-1)(x-3)$ is rational. If $x=\sqrt2-1$, then $(x+1)(x+3)$, $x$, and $(x-1)(x-3)$ are all irrational, but $(x+1)^2$ is rational. Still, it's best if you edit THE EXACT WORDING of the answer into the body of your question (and best if you don't ignore comments).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am sorry that I miss one important condition in the question. Edit and write all words of question. Thanks for you help!

Comment: OK – now we have something to work with! So: can you prove that Condition 1 is sufficient?

Comment: Yes. $(x+1)^2=(x+1)(x+3)-2x-2$ is irrational, similarly to $(x-1)(x-3)$

Comment: Good. So, you can solve the whole problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks for you whole help!